# stored procudure variaibles in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am declaring variables inside the procedure and setting those values to result from another query.when executed it is giving null.

version:8.0.16

```
call putrequest('x',"jiraUPM","ASE-12345","inprogress","testcybsjira.com");
```

requestId and reqid are not null.but it taking null value .

```
create procedure `putrequest`(in `employeeId` varchar(15),in `reqtype` 
 varchar(15),in `ticketId` varchar(15),in `status` varchar(15),in `details` 
 varchar(100))
 begin
  declare `rid` int;
  declare `reqType` int;
  select `requestId` into  `reqType` from `requesttype` where `request`=`reqtype`;
  select `reqId` into `rid` from `employee` where `empId`=`employeeId`;
  insert into `requests` values(rid,reqType,`ticketId`,NOW(),NOW(),`status`,`details`);
 end
```

> Error executing SQL statement. Column 'reqId' cannot be null - Connection: Connection 1: 93ms

Comment: You cannot store a result set in a variable. Sample data would help clarify what you are trying to do(as is you don't say)

Answer (score 0):

If either of the `SELECT` queries doens't find a matching row, the corresponding variable will be `NULL`, and you'll get an error when you try to insert it. You need to check for that before doing the `INSERT`.

But there's no need for separate `SELECT` queries and variables, use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

```
INSERT INTO requests
SELECT e.reqId, r.requestId, ticketId, NOW(), NOW(), status, details
FROM requesttype AS r
CROSS JOIN employee AS e
WHERE r.request = reqtype
AND e.empId = employeeId
```

If `reqtype` or `employeeId` can't be found, the join won't return any rows, so nothing will be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a problem because of the same variable name "reqtype" (declare as a procedure parameter) and "reqType" (Declare as procedure variable)

It considers the null value for reqtype and not return any record.

MySQL is case insensitive . Be careful while given variable name.

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure `putrequest`(in `employeeId` varchar(50),in `rtype` 
 varchar(50),in `ticketId` varchar(15),in `status` varchar(15),in `details` 
 varchar(100))
begin
  declare `rid` int;
  declare `reqType` int;
  select `reqId` into `rid` from `employee` where `empId`=`employeeId`;
  select `requestId` into  `reqType` from requesttype where `request`=`rtype`;
  insert into `requests` values(rid,reqType,`ticketId`,NOW(),NOW(),`status`,`details`);
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Uv9Wdq3KLGxrF3ok9AhSm/0)